# How to use SMOTE in Java Weka API?

Tags: machine-learning, java, weka

I am trying to build classification model using Java Weka API. My training dataset have class imbalance problems. For this reason, I want to use SMOTE to reduce class  imbalance problem. But, I do not know how to use it in Java Weka API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the community.

You can use the following code:

```
import weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import weka.filters.Filter;

Instances data = DataSource.read(".../file.arff"); //Dataset 

SMOTE smote=new SMOTE();  //create object of SMOTE
smote.setInputFormat(data);
Instances data_smote = Filter.useFilter(data, smote); //Apply SMOTE on Dataset
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I am trying to applying your code.

Comment: I am glad to hear that.